# How to get the corresponding variable name to its corresponding value C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script. I am trying to find out the distance between the player and each of the four corners of the map. It returns the distances between each corner successfully (distanceC1 = Corner 1 etc) and also finds out the corner furthest away from the player.

I am trying to get that corner gameobject name as the "largestDistanceName". The corner that corresponds with the furthest distance.

Eg. IF DistanceC3 is the furthest, make largestDistanceName equal to the gameobject Corner3and so forth.

I am not sure how to do that. Thank you

```
  public GameObject Corner1;
  public GameObject Corner2;
  public GameObject Corner3;
  public GameObject Corner4;


  public float distanceC1;
  public float distanceC2;
  public float distanceC3;
  public float distanceC4;




    distanceC1 =Vector3.Distance(Corner1.transform.position,ThePlayer.transform.position);
    distanceC2 =Vector3.Distance(Corner2.transform.position,ThePlayer.transform.position);
    distanceC3 =Vector3.Distance(Corner3.transform.position,ThePlayer.transform.position);
    distanceC4 =Vector3.Distance(Corner4.transform.position,ThePlayer.transform.position);
    float[] DistanceArray = {distanceC1, distanceC2, distanceC3, distanceC4};
    float maxValueDistance = DistanceArray.Max();
    LargestDistance = maxValueDistance;
    LargestDistanceName = INSERT SCRIPT THAT FETCHES CornerX corresponding to the distance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Transform GetFarthestCorner( Transform from, params Transform[] corners )
{
    Transform farthestCorner = null ;
    float maxDistance = -1 ;

    for( int cornerIndex = 0 ; cornerIndex < corners.Length ; ++cornerIndex )
    {
        float distance = ( corners[cornerIndex].position - from.position ).sqrMagnitude ;
        if( distance > maxDistance )
        {
            farthestCorner = corners[cornerIndex];
            maxDistance = distance ;
        }
    }

    return farthestCorner ;
}
```

---

How to use :

```
Transform farthestCorner = GetFarthestCorner( ThePlayer.transform, Corner1.transform, Corner2.transform, Corner3.transform, Corner4.transform ) ;
float distance = Vector3.Distance( farthestCorner.position, ThePlayer.transform.position ) ;
```

Comment: How would I set this farthest corner to be the vector3 target for a navmesh agent to transform to. Like this code.         Vector3 target = transform.position - Vector3.forward * goalDistance; // transform.position +- Vector3.forward
          agent.SetDestination(target);

Comment: `Transform farthestCorner = GetFarthestCorner( ... ) ; agent.SetDestination( farthestCorner.position - Vector3.forward * goalDistance ); `

Answer (score 0):

All of your code can be replaced with a simple LINQ query

```
// assuming you have...
List<GameObject> corners;
GameObject player;

var closestCornerName = corners
    // order collection of corners by the distance to player, descending
    .OrderByDescending(corner =>
        Vector3.Distance(corner.transform.position, player.transform.position)) 
    // take the first (furthest) one
    .First()
    // take its name
    .name;
```

Comment: AFAIK, all the features of LINQ are not supported on iOS, especially the ordering functions. But it may have been fixed.